# Extracting properties from jpeg/png images, INCLUDING greyscale depth (8 levels of grey, 16 levels, etc...)

Tags: vb6, png, jpeg, gdi

I'm writing code in VB5, trying to extract some properties from image files, both jpeg and png. With GDI32 I manage to get width and height, but I can't find a way to understand the number of levels of grey.

Black/White (1 bit) to 16 levels (4 bit) are all below 1 byte, then the bytes per pixel do not help me. Is there a way to tell 16-level-of-grey image from a 256-level-of-grey one?

And a way to tell a color 16-bit image from a greyscale 16-bit one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Grey's are still colours. The only differenece is the colour values in the palletes (for bitmaps anyway). JPEG colour space is a whole different animal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest checking out LaVolpe's Alpha Image Control ([vbforums.com](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=630193)). He's mastered image manipulation for a variety of formats including PNG and JPEG using VB6 and GDI+. It's an amazing piece of code.